# How to assign the (filtered) response of an Axios request to a variable in VueJS?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, axios, google-chrome-devtools

I have an Axios request through which the response is an object:

[image]

I've filtered the response like so:

```
response.data.value_table_cols.map(col => col.header)
```

To get the following array as a result - In relation to the above image it's the data under value_table_rows:

```
["row 1", "row 2", "row 3"]
```

When you log response.data.value_table_cols.map(col => col.header) to the console it produces the above array. So, how can I assign *response.data.value_table_cols.map(col => col.header)* to a data variable called, say, allOfTheRows?

In a Vue JS page:

```
data: () => ({
      allOfTheRows: []
}),
```

My Axios request:

```
    getTable(table) {
        var self = this;

        axios.get(window.routes["value-tables.get"].replace("{value_table}", table.id))
            .then(function (response) {
                self.$refs.hotTableComponent.hotInstance.loadData(response.data.value_table_rows.map(row => row.value_table_cells));
                this.allOfTheRows = response.data.value_table_rows.map(row => row.header)
                console.log(response.data.value_table_rows.map(row => row.header));
            })

            .catch(function(error){
                console.error(error);
                if (!!error.response) console.log(error.response);
            });
    },
```

As instructed by the first answer I've rewritten the request like so:

```
    getTable(table) {
        var self = this;

        apiClient.get(window.routes["value-tables.get"].replace("{value_table}", table.id))
            .then(function (response) {
                self.$refs.hotTableComponent.hotInstance.loadData(response.data.value_table_rows.map(row => row.value_table_cells));
                this.allOfTheRows = response.data.value_table_rows.map(row => row.header)
            })

            .catch(function(error){
                console.error(error);
                if (!!error.response) console.log(error.response);
            });
    },
```

However it gave the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing:

```
apiClient.get(window.routes["value-tables.get"].replace("{value_table}", table.id))

        .then((response) => {
                   this.allOfTheRows = response.data.value_table_rows.map(row => row.value_table_cells));
             }
```

**Note** that I changed the function into an arrow to get implicit binding of `this`

Also, I would do the map function in a separate method, to have space for some validation too

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've tried it however it gave me the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
(I may be writing it wrongly in the request so I've put in the question how I've written it)

Comment: Remove the first then() block. In my answer I meant to replace the part I added. I edit my answer to include the whole block

Comment: Take a better look at my answer code. If you get that error it means you are using `function(response){}` instead of `(response)=>{}`, thats why `this` is undefined.

Comment: I think data needs to be referenced like data[0] I see your using a map, but not flattening it, so you might have all your data there just not using it properly

Comment: The code I've written incorrectly was using **this**.allOfTheRows. Since I declared var self = this; at the beginning of the method, I was supposed to use self.allOfTheRows. But thank you, your answer works!

Comment: Ah yeah I missed it. Yes, you could have used self.allOfTheRows instead. I'm used to use ES6 as much as possible, despite in vue there is some caveat of using it.